# IIS_IUSRS permission vs ApplicationPoolIdentity

Tags: iis, iis-8.5, application-pools

I was looking for the difference in permissions when:
- App pool is running with ApplicationPoolIdentity
- App pool's identity is set as a local system user account which belongs to IIS_IUSRS group only

Is there any problem if the second option above is used instead of the first one?

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/manage/configuring-security/application-pool-identities